# How to record execution time of all Procedures in MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to record execution time of all procedures in MySql.

For example, I have a database named test and it contains 25 procedures. When a procedure runs, I'd like each execution time to be recorded in a separate table.

Comment: The general and/or slow log will tell you that (and more).

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Add timing code in each proc.

Plan B:  Add timing code around the `CALLs`.

Plan C:  Use the slowlog (with a low value in `long_query_time`) to capture the timings for individual calls; then use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the results.

`long_query_time = 0` will flood the disk with the slowlog; be cautious.  `=0.5` will catch only queries (such as `CALL`) that take longer than half a second.  If you are primarily looking for the "slowest", this may be a better option.  See:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog